# remove some countries from ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have to remove some countries e.g.Mexico from the list of countries displayed in ngx-intl-tel-input.

I tried 'excludeCountries' option but it's not working.

HTML file:

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input class="form-control"
    [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
    [enablePlaceholder]="false"
    [searchCountryFlag]="true"
    [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
    [selectFirstCountry]="false"
    [selectedCountryISO]="ES"
    [maxLength]="15"
    [separateDialCode]="true"
    [phoneValidation]="true"
    [excludeCountries] = "['MX']"
    [preferredCountries] = "[CountryISO.Spain]">
</ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states, there is no `excludeCountries` input. Instead, you should provide the `onlyCountries` with all the countries excluding the country that you don't want.

Iterate the keys of `CountryISO` enum and exclude the `CountryISO.Mexico`.

```
onlyCountries: CountryISO[] = Object.keys(CountryISO)
    .filter((x) => CountryISO[x] != CountryISO.Mexico)
    .map((x) => CountryISO[x]);
```

If you want to exclude multiple countries, you can work as below:

```
onlyCountries: CountryISO[] = Object.keys(CountryISO)
  .filter((x) => ![CountryISO.Mexico, /* Other CountryISO */].some(y => y == CountryISO[x]))
  .map((x) => CountryISO[x]);
```

Provide the `onlyCountries` to `[onlyCountries]` input.

```
<ngx-intl-tel-input
  class="form-control"
  [enableAutoCountrySelect]="true"
  [enablePlaceholder]="false"
  [searchCountryFlag]="true"
  [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
  [selectFirstCountry]="false"
  [selectedCountryISO]="ES"
  [maxLength]="15"
  [separateDialCode]="true"
  [phoneValidation]="true"
  [onlyCountries]="onlyCountries"
  [preferredCountries]="[CountryISO.Spain]"
>
</ngx-intl-tel-input>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-intl-tel-input-demo-ng-12-wysamz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)